# Save in DB js-generated field in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a form in Rails, very basic. But I decided to add some features. Little bit of context.
You choose either you're a man or a woman, and then the form generate some field. I had a field that was already existing in the V1, but when I generate it with javascript, it's not saved in DB. I don't really understand why. Here are some code.

## Controller

```
def create
  @pokemon = Pokemon.new(params[:pokefuck])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @pokemon.save
      format.html { redirect_to '/pokemons', notice: 'pokemon was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @pokemon, status: :created, location: @pokemon }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @pokemon.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

## View

Original field that works

```
<%= f.select "size", options_for_select(size, @pokemon.size) %>
```

size is a hash

Created one, that does not work

```
var s = document.createElement("select");
s.name = "po";
s.id = "pokemon_size";
sex.appendChild(s);
for(i in size) {
  document.formName.po.options[i] = new Option(size[i], size[i]);
}
```

I supposed it was because the name of my new element wasn't pokemon[size], but when I used this, the line document.formName.pokemon[size].options[i] didn't work anymore.

So I'm kinda struggling to see how I can make this works.
Thanks!

Comment: It might be because your new fields are created on the fly and hence not part of the original DOM.

Comment: So that would mean I have to create two different forms ? Meh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from your controller code that your form fields are namespaced into "pokefuck", then you'll need to make the name of your select "pokefuck[size]", and then reference that name in the form's elements collection:

```
var s = document.createElement("select");
s.name = "pokefuck[size]";
s.id = "pokemon_size";
sex.appendChild(s);
for(i in size) {
  document.formName.elements['pokefuck[size]'].options[i] = new Option(size[i], size[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the field needs to put it into the params hash for you your `pokefuck`.

`pokefuck[size]` should be the name of the form element. Append the form element to the form element you're submitting.